# How can I use an Artifactory created in JFrog in my Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, automation, client

I created a client and uploaded it to JFrog. I need to import it into my Maven project. What dependencies should I add to the pom.xml ? And how do I use the methods created within my project?

I tried to use the SET ME UP option provided by JFrog, but I don't know how to configure the POM and then how to use the client.

Comment: Is [Manually Overriding the Built-in Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository#MavenRepository-ManuallyOverridingtheBuilt-inRepositories) not working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.